# Is there anyway to make this code cleaner?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, code-cleanup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/'
urlb = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/'
urlc = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/c/'
result = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'lxml')
college = doc.find_all(string="Kentucky")
result = requests.get(urlb)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'lxml')
collegeb = doc.find_all(string='Kentucky')
result = requests.get(urlc)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'lxml')
collegec = doc.find_all(string='Kentucky')
print(college)
print(collegeb)
print(collegec)
```

I need to do this for every letter of the alphabet for like at least 30 schools and I would really like to know how to do this more efficiently

Comment: A better site for improving working code might be [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deduplicate nearly identical code with a loop over inputs and a `list` or `dict` of results:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url_template = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/{}/'
folders = ['a', 'b', 'c']  # The only varying thing in your original tripled code
colleges = []              # Store the results for each varied thing here in same order
for folder in folders:     # Loop over varying component
    result = requests.get(url_template.format(folder))  # Substitute it in template
    doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'lxml')
    colleges.append(doc.find_all(string="Kentucky"))    # Append result in same order

# Loop over results to print them
for college in colleges:
    print(college)
```

If you're having it work for many schools, for every letter of the alphabet, you'd likely use a `dict` (better, a `defaultdict`) for the results instead of a `list` (so you can group the results by school) with an inner loop parsing out data by school:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import defaultdict
from string import ascii_lowercase

url_template = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/{}/'
folders = ascii_lowercase  # Will run for every lowercase alphabet letter

schoolnames = ("Kentucky", "Gonzaga", ...)
colleges = defaultdict(list) # Store a list of results for each school

for folder in folders:     # Loop over varying component
    result = requests.get(url_template.format(folder))  # Substitute it in template
    doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'lxml')
    for schoolname in schoolnames:
        colleges[schoolname].append(doc.find_all(schoolname=school))

# Loop over results to print them
for collegename, results in colleges.items():
    print(collegename)
    for result in results:
        print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly simpler code to do that. All I'm doing is pulling in all the player tables, then use `.value_counts()` on the `'Colleges'` column. This will get you all schools. Then if you only want to see one school, just call out that index value:

```
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_lowercase

dfs_list = []
for letter in ascii_lowercase:
    url = f'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/{letter}/'
    dfs_list.append(pd.read_html(url)[0])
    print(url)
    
results = pd.concat(dfs_list, axis=0)
colleges_count = results['Colleges'].value_counts()
```

You could even convert this in fewer lines of code with list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_lowercase

results = pd.concat([pd.read_html(f'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/{letter}/')[0] for letter in ascii_lowercase], axis=0)
colleges_count = results['Colleges'].value_counts()
```

**Output:**

```
print(colleges_count)
Kentucky                                  112
UCLA                                       91
UNC                                        91
Duke                                       84
Kansas                                     72

Kansas, Houston                             1
California Western Uiversity                1
Florida, Louisiana                          1
NC State, Iona College                      1
Seattle Pacific University, Washington      1
Name: Colleges, Length: 806, dtype: int64
```

Or just see a certain school:

```
print(colleges_count['Kentucky'])
112
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a `for` loop.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
colleges = []
for char in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
    url = f"https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/{char}/"
    result = requests.get(url)
    doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'lxml')
    college = doc.find_all(string="Kentucky")
    colleges.append(college)
print(*colleges, sep = "\n")
```

Comment: The problem also involves multiple colleges.

Comment: Well, the goal was to show a way to make the code cleaner instead of spoon-feeding the total solution

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function with the instructions you need to "re-do" for every school. Then you deploy a `main()` func with every parameter or characteristic/trait for every school. Your code seems a big chunk of lines, you should separate them in different instructions and rely your work more on *"tidy-coding"*